# How to check the equality of 2 Pandas Series objects?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am comparing 2 Pandas Series objects using the .equals() method.
Here are 2 examples of objects I'm comparing:

```
KAARTNUMMER                  XXX
VOLLEDIGE_NAAM    Test
KLAS                               YYY
Name: ID, dtype: object
KAARTNUMMER                    XXX
VOLLEDIGE_NAAM    Test
KLAS                               YYY
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

I compare them using the following code:

```
if not series1.equals(series2):
    print("not equals")
```

My code is always reaching the print statement while it shouldn't get there because the Series objects are cleary the same.

I already reorganized the columns to be in the same order because I read somewhere this could have an impact, but this didn't work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue (python 3.8.5, pandas 1.2.1).

Comment: I get the Series objects out of a dataframe by using df.loc[XXX] where XXX is an index. Idk if this does something?

Comment: How did you create series1 and series2 before the if statement? Maybe try series2 = series1. Then run the logic as a test.

Comment: @Mkay can't see any change in behaviour whether it's standalone Series or getting them as you specified: still shows equality and doesn't go through to print statement.

Comment: Try: (series1 == series2).all()

Comment: I get both series objects from 2 different Dataframes, maybe the problem lays here?

Comment: I tried (series1 == series2).all(), still returns False

Comment: Maybe series1 and series2 are not equal as pandas.Series  They might not have the same indices or the same element order.